# php code works fine on xampp localhost but not working on live server

Tags: php

I have uploaded all the php files on live server same as on localhost. Few files works fine. But my registration page is not working when i try to register it does not store data in phpmyadmin. and shows the error as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7DaJ.png)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Event Management</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <!--<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
        <link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Database file include -->
        <?php require_once ('main.php'); ?>
        <!-- Database file include End -->
        <div class="container justify-content-center">
            <h2 align="center">Log In or Sign Up</h2>
                <div class="container">
                <form method="post" action="main.php">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
                            <label></label>
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username"/>
                            <label></label>
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
                            <label></label>
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email"/>
                            <label></label>
                            <label></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="contact" name="contact"/>
                            <label></label>
                            <label></label><br />
                            <button class="btn btn-info" id="register" name="register">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <label>Already have an Account?</label>
                            <a href="login.php" style="color:#03F !important;">Login Here.</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.php file code for registration

```
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['contact']))
{
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $uName = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $date = date('d-m-yy');
    
    $mysqli->query("insert into register(Name,username,password,Email_Id,Phone_No,
    date_Created) values('$Name','$uName','$pass','$mail','$contact','$date')") or die($mysqli->error);
    $mysqli->query("insert into users(email,user_name,pass_word) select r.Email_Id, r.username, r.password from     register r where r.Email_Id NOT IN (SELECT email FROM users);") or die($mysqli->error);
    echo "Data inserted successfully!";
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? maybe try turning on error_reporting or check your logs

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: Use ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);   to see what error you are getting.

Comment: the error is HTTP ERROR 500. @Not A Bot

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);   by using these 3 line of code, you will get what exactly the error is.. Error code 500 means there is some error in your code. Thus these 3 line of code will tell you what is that error

Comment: in the same file i have to write this code? @Not A Bot

Comment: Yes you can try, but also add these like of code in your ``main.php`` as that file might have some issue

Comment: Ok Thank You! @Not A Bot

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: Whenever you get Error Code 500, that means some issue in your code. Thus by using these 3 lines of code you can get what is the error. @YeshalShah

Comment: Yes! I got the error it say "Undefined variable: mysqli" in main.php file. @Not A Bot

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to increase your chances of receiving a positive response to your query please read and consider the points raised in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You've an error on main.php line number 73.

Undefined variable: mysqli

Please show more to view & get your solution.

Thanks

Comment: have you got your solution?

Comment: if you may share your code with me so  I can help better.

Comment: @YeshalShah  I think you are forgetting this line ``$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");``  After this only you can use    ``$mysqli->query`` and other commands.

Comment: can you please share you main.php file?